# ubuntu 22.04 slow graphic session startup - how to improve

Tags: boot, 22.04, gnome-shell

I'm looking at having a shorter time from "switch on" to "having logged in and ready to launch an application". The major "time eater" seems to be the start up of gdm and/or gnome-shell. Am I correct, and if yes, why gnome takes that long to boot up? Anything that can be done (apart buying a more recent/better hardware)? :)

Many thanks for help/ideas/suggestions! :D

```
## hardware: ##

laptop multi-boot (win10/linux)  
core i3-4005U CPU @ 1.70GHz  
8GB memory  
mechanical HD (no SSD)
```

```
## critycal chain: ##

graphical.target @1min 42.018s  
└─multi-user.target @1min 42.017s  
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @44.318s +57.698s  
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @44.254s +58ms  
      └─network.target @44.192s  
        └─NetworkManager.service @34.344s +9.846s  
          └─dbus.service @34.339s  
            └─basic.target @34.276s  
              └─sockets.target @34.276s  
                └─snapd.socket @34.234s +41ms  
                  └─sysinit.target @34.104s  
                    └─systemd-timesyncd.service @1min 17.327s +126ms  
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @30.356s +1.012s  
                        └─local-fs.target @30.095s  
                          └─snap-cups-980.mount @1min 34.443s +26ms  
                            └─local-fs-pre.target @9.513s  
                              └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @8.179s +1.334s  
                                └─systemd-sysusers.service @4.665s +3.485s  
                                  └─systemd-remount-fs.service @4.468s +168ms  
                                    └─systemd-journald.socket @4.354s  
                                      └─system.slice @4.327s  
                                        └─-.slice @4.327s
```

```
## blame: ##
57.698s plymouth-quit-wait.service  
46.023s dev-loop11.device  
42.884s e2scrub_reap.service  
23.673s systemd-journal-flush.service  
21.921s snapd.service  
21.346s apt-daily-upgrade.service  
18.956s dev-sda6.device  
18.529s networkd-dispatcher.service  
15.345s accounts-daemon.service  
14.366s fwupd.service  
13.852s cups.service
```

Comment: for some reason, salutation at begin gets lost, so adding here :)   "Hi There!"

Comment: Search google using `site:askubuntu.com etworkd-dispatcher.service` (as an example) and most will show you how relevant a service is and if it is a good idea to stop the service.  For instance: do you have printers? if not disable cups service.  do you use snaps? if not disable it. if you do see if you can replace those softwares by apt and disable snapd. Go through each of them and do a reboot after each to see what happens

Comment: "mechanical HD (no SSD)" this might be the biggest issue. an ssd is a boot of about 7 up to 13 sec.  A hdd ....might be 20, 30 sec just because of it being a hdd.

Comment: Look at your system startup log (watch your kernel discover the hardware) with the terminal command `sudo journalctl  -b 0`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! I'm actually aiming at the graphic session. I already went through the "service clean up" part. From the critical chain I get to the  systemd-user-session in about 44 sec. I'm ok with that. But to get to the multiuser/graphic target it takes about 1min more! From about 44sec to about 1min 42sec. Why??? That is the part I'd like ti understand/optimize